# My htaccess file broke my CSS and JavaScript files

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am missing something in my .htaccess,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# CATEGORIES
    RewriteRule ^categories/(.*)$               /newwebsite/rewrite_cats.php?category=$1 [L,NC]

# PRODUCT AND SERVICES
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$                     /newwebsite/rewrite.php?sub=$1&second=$2 [L,NC]
```

I don't know what's wrong with this, but when I access my site I cannot see the styles and JavaScript being applied, it works if I remove this line:

```
    RewriteRule ^categories/(.*)$               /newwebsite/rewrite_cats.php?category=$1 [L,NC]
```

The errors I get in my Chrome console are the following:

```
Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html:
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html:
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html:
```

If I remove or comment the first RewriteRule line, everything works.
I have no idea what's going on, can anyone help me?

I have realized it is something about combining these two rules. when I comment the second one everything works perfect.

Answer (score 3):

Add

```
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

before your rules

Oh, and I hope you're using **absolute** paths for your CSS

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I already have those lines in my htaccess, and yes I am using absolute paths.

Comment: @human Are you sure you are using absolute paths not relative paths? This is most likely the issue!

Comment: That is my html code, <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/newwebsite/css/style.css">, definitly is an htaccess error because I tried to access one of these css files in my browser directly, http://somesite.com/styles.css and I get my index.php in the browser.

Comment: I'm not sure, but you may have to add the RewriteCond lines before each rule. See if it works then.

Comment: @human then "/newwebsite/css/style.css" does not actually point at where your css file is

Comment: Yes, it does. As I mentioned before if I comment this line RewriteRule ^categories/(.*)$ /newwebsite/rewrite_cats.php?category=$1 [L,NC] everything works fine.

Comment: sorry, somesite.com/styles.css is just an invented path. it would be {somesite}.com/newwebsite/css/style.css